# DB2 equivalent for MySQL's DROP .. IF EXISTS

Tags: db2

Is there an equivalent in DB2 for MySQL's (or PostgreSQL's):

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sometable;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [No.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140831162412/http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1005265-drop-table-if-exists.html)

You'll need an `IF` clause to check for the existence of the table and then a separate statement to actually drop it if it does exist.

Comment: @ivotron : Nick's right on this one. An example of Nick's answer is in StackOverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3976691/491757. BTW +1 for Nick !!!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493055/drop-a-db2-view-if-it-exists/2493475#2493475):

Create the stored function `db2perf_quiet_drop()`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db2perf_quiet_drop( IN statement VARCHAR(1000) )
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
   DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
   DECLARE NotThere    CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42704';
   DECLARE NotThereSig CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42883';

   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NotThere, NotThereSig
      SET SQLSTATE = '     ';

   SET statement = 'DROP ' || statement;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement;
END
```

and use it as `Begin atomic call db2perf_quiet_drop('table my_table'); End`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an annonymous block

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42704'
   BEGIN END;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE sometable';
END @
```